# Rewriting of a sigma-algebra in "An first look at rigorous probability".

Tags: measure-theory

on page 12 in the second edition of the book "An first look at rigorous probability" by Rosenthal, the following is stated:

> We now set $$M=\left\{A\subseteq\Omega;P^{*}\left(A\cap E\right)+P^{*}(A^{C}\cap E)=P^{*}(E) \forall E \subseteq\Omega\right\}$$ That is, $M$ is the set of all subsets $A$ with the property that $P^{*}$ is additive on the union of $A \cap E$ with $A^{C}\cap E$, for all subsets $E$. Note that by subadditivity we always have $P^{*}(A\cap E)+P^{*}(A^{C} \cap E)\geq P^{*}(E)$, so $M$ is equivalent to $$ M=\left\{A\subseteq\Omega;P^{*}\left(A\cap E\right)+P^{*}(A^{C}\cap E)\leq P^{*}(E)\forall E\subseteq\Omega\right\}$$

What I do not understand is why the second definition of M uses the $\leq$ equal symbol, while in my opinion it should use $\geq$. Could someone shed some light for me on this? Please point out the mistake in my reasoning.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalence is correct as stated, with the $\leqslant$ symbol. The equivalence holds because an equality can be viewed as two inequalities. As noted in Rosenthal, $P^*(A \cap E) + P^*(A^c \cap E) \leqslant P(E)$ is the only "difficult" direction for the inequality. To see that it is sufficient, suppose that $A$ satisfies
$$P^*(A \cap E) + P^*(A^c \cap E) \leqslant P^*(E).$$
for all $E \subset \Omega$. 
Moreover, 
\begin{align*}
P^*(E) &= P^*(E \cap A \cup E \cap A^c) \\
&\leqslant P^*(E \cap A) + P^*(E\cap A^c),
\end{align*}
because presumably $P^*$ is an outer measure and is therefore subadditive. This last inequality is true for *any* $A \subset \Omega$ and for this reason $P^*(E \cap A) + P^*(E \cap A^c) \geqslant P(E)$ is not required in the definition. Combining the two inequalities,
$$P^*(E \cap A) + P^*(E\cap A^c) \leqslant P^*(E) \leqslant P^*(E \cap A) + P^*(E\cap A^c),$$
and so we must have equalities throughout. This is exactly the first definition.

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer my question. It's simply brilliant.